# After installing RVM and updating ruby, RSpec stopped working

Tags: rspec, rvm, rspec-rails

I'm trying to get rspec to start working again.  When I go to test anything, I get the following:

```
stacyrandel$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
/Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': /Users/stacyrandel/rails_projects/callred/app/models/user.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
               ^
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:260:in `safe_constantize'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `safe_constantize'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:152:in `_default_wrap_model'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:169:in `_set_wrapper_defaults'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:133:in `inherited'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/railties/routes_helpers.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/rails_projects/callred/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/rails_projects/callred/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/rails_projects/callred/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `require'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/rails_projects/callred/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/rails_projects/callred/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/rails_projects/callred/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `load'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `map'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_in_process'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /Users/stacyrandel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into your source file `/Users/stacyrandel/rails_projects/callred/app/models/user.rb` line `21`, make sure that `uniqueness` is used in proper context according to this tutorial: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#uniqueness

As pointed out by @dpassage in the other answer there are differences between ruby versions:

1. Ruby 1.8.7:

   ```
   validates :email, :uniqueness => true
   ```
2. Ruby 1.9+:

   ```
   validates :email, uniqueness: true
   ```

But your stacktrace shows that ruby 1.9.3 was used, so it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the important line in the stack trace is this one:

```
/Users/stacyrandel/rails_projects/callred/app/models/user.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

That says there's a syntax error in your code. It might be because for some reason you're using Ruby 1.8.x to run code that's using the 1.9.3 hash syntax. Or it might be something else. Can you post additional lines from that file?